# Não renderiza o resultado com o .map no React

Tags: javascript, react

Usei o useState para setar o valor de uma const, para poder mostrar o resultado de um fetch, mas não mostra ( usei o debugger para ver como chegava, chega com o resultado mas não renderiza )

Codigo:

```
  export default () => {
      const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(async () => {
        let list = await Tmdb.getHomeList();
        setMovieList(list);
        console.log(list);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div className="page">
          <section className="lists">
            {movieList.map((item) => {
              <div>{item.title}</div>;
            })}
          </section>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, como sua callback do useEffect é assincrona, provavelmente seu código irá quebrar ao tentar acessar o item.title, para corrigir este erro, você pode adicionar um novo state "loading" como false por exemplo, e o alterar para true quando a promise do fetch estiver concluída.

```
 export default () => {
  const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(async () => {
    let list = await Tmdb.getHomeList();
    setMovieList(list);
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(list);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="page">
      <section className="lists">
        { loading && movieList.map((item) => {
          <div>{item.title}</div>;
        })}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Cara, agradeço muito pela resposta, mas tu acredita que eu fiquei tão encucado com isso que eu mesmo descobri o erro, o meu erro ta no meu .map, eu não coloquei o return, e existe um "arrow" de return, que ao invés de abrir a arrow function com { } se abre com ( ) pq ai anula a necessidade de ter um return